# Can iCloud show a phone when find my iPhone is turned off?

Tags: itunes, icloud, find-my-iphone

If I have my find my iPhone turned off, does it still show up on iCloud that the phone is turned on?

Comment: What are you trying to do with find my phone? Taken literally, your question is a simple no.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

If you have disabled Find My iPhone on your iPhone in Settings.app -> iCloud -> Find My iPhone, you will no longer be able to tell if the phone is on (and connected to internet) nor will you be able to locate the iPhone. The device will simply no longer show in Find My iPhone.